# Clarification for IBM Challenge and questions as such

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

This question here [ansatz to VQE in Portfolio Optimization](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/25768/ansatz-to-vqe-in-portfolio-optimization) specifically asked for help to IBM Challenge clarification. One thing I would like to know/understand better is the following:

1. I don't know about the IBM Challenge; nevertheless, isn't asking
   something as such here considered cheating?

2. In general, for computing/coding with quantum competitions should we
   allow these questions? Or only allow if the questions reflect
   clarifications and not direct answers?

Comment: yes, including the Qiskit Global Summer School, need to over at least a week or two for the lab submission deadline to over.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question for this specific case: I believe the IBM Challenge referenced has already passed (see [this page](https://challenges.quantum-computing.ibm.com/fall-2021)) - and in this sense, I do think this is not a bad thing to ask about. Certainly if the IBM Challenge was currently in progress we'd delete such a question, I think.

More generally, I think we can probably approach questions like these as follows:

1. Is the competition/event currently in progress? If so, delete the question, potentially inviting the questioner to re-ask after the event is over/solutions have been released, if applicable.
2. If we were unaware of the question being part of some competition, would it be a good question? If so, I think the question is fine. If not, the issues are probably already addressed via the current close reasons/editing/etc. I think this test is the one the question you linked fails - it needs some editing for clarity (quoting the text of the specific challenge, for instance), as well as elaboration from the OP as to the context of their question (their conceptual difficulty, for instance, or where they got stuck with the problem).

This is just an initial response, and I'd be interested in what the community has to say more generally!

Comment: I agree. I don't think there's that much more to say than this. Close for ongoing competitions, same way we do it for posts blatantly asking to get homework solved, and for not ongoing events, treat them as we would any other post. Only thing is I'm not sure whether deleting is warranted for this, rather than just closing (not that it would make much of a difference: such closed posts would most likely end up auto-deleted in time anyway)

Comment: I also agree. I vaguely remembering having to do something like this with a question in the past (I maybe put it on hold until the competition was over or something similar)